Не устанавливается бибилиотека pyaudio

Уже 4 день пытаюсь установить его - все честно попробовал, вообще почти все

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Ну смотрите это я просто вбиваю pip install PyAudio и выдаёт это

Вы хоть текстом прикрепите трасировку... мне с телефона вообще не разобрать. Поберегите глаза окружающих.

Скорее всего под Питон 3.13 ещё не портировали, под 3.12 пишут вроде есть уже готовая сборка. Так что лучше всего поставить более старый Питон.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
